# React/Ionic Spotify Authorization redirection

Tags: python, reactjs, docker, ionic-framework, microservices

I am coding up a Spotify app with a microservices architecture.

I have a few services, including a frontend (built in React/Ionic) and an auth service (Python FastAPI). These services are running in docker-compose.

I have the auth service handling all of the Spotify Authentication, and I just need a button on the front end to redirect to the Spotify login page.

[image: onclick button event]

above is the code that is executed when the button is clicked. I have a setupProxy.js file configured, so the url is fine.

The flow is this : button click > GET request to auth service > auth service returns a redirect response > once user is logged in, Spotify redirects back to auth service with code, should post access code to database. Then return to frontend page. The frontend will pull the access code from the database.

The problem is I am not getting redirected to the spotify page from the frontend. I know the redirect works, because I have another backend service, which I made a test call to the auth service from and it redirects me.

[image: login route on auth service]

This is what is executed on the auth service call.

[image: backend service]

This is the test call from the backend to auth that definitely works.

I basically need an equivalent of the /test route above in React/Ionic.

Any help would be appreciated as I am completely stuck.

Update:

[image: spotify code]

Spotify code is now coming through (i.e. button is clicked, browser redirects to my auth service, then redirects again to callback address with access code in URL, but even on a new browser I am not asked to sign into spotify it just comes straight back.